# Is There a Way to Prevent MassTransit From Taking Down Our Service?

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

We're seeing one exception that, if I recall correctly, should be fixed in MT 3.0 (we're on 3.1) we see this when we have our environment under a very high load:

```
Exception Info: RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.AlreadyClosedException
Stack:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__1(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

This exception is causing our windows service to crash and someone has to go start it back up. Is there an event or some configuration we can setup at a higher level to handle these unforeseen scenarios?

I know there are [bus events](http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/usage/busevents.html), but no even specific to exceptions outside of my message handling.

I also saw there is [exception handling](http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/usage/exceptions.html), unfortunately this is only good for scenarios where there's an error while processing a message. Not for when RabbitMQ throws an exception unrelated to retrieving or sending a message.

I just added some logging and service level restart logic, will update this with more details if available in the future.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledException;

public void UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    // Shut down, dispose, reinitialize internal objects and log messages.
}
```

---

### Edit 1 - RabbitMQ Logs

We saw this error at 11:37:47, in all 3 of the rabbitmq servers we're seeing these type of logs:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 5-May-2016::11:37:06 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.925.14> (10.50.0.3:59625 -> 10.50.0.123:5672)

=ERROR REPORT==== 5-May-2016::11:37:10 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.917.14> (10.50.0.3:59588 -> 10.50.0.123:5672):
{handshake_timeout,handshake}

=WARNING REPORT==== 5-May-2016::11:37:15 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.614.14> (10.50.0.3:58645 -> 10.50.0.123:5672):
connection_closed_abruptly

=ERROR REPORT==== 5-May-2016::11:37:16 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.925.14> (10.50.0.3:59625 -> 10.50.0.123:5672):
{handshake_timeout,handshake}

=INFO REPORT==== 5-May-2016::11:37:17 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.941.14> (10.50.0.3:59665 -> 10.50.0.123:5672)

=WARNING REPORT==== 5-May-2016::11:37:24 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.642.14> (10.50.0.3:58726 -> 10.50.0.123:5672):
connection_closed_abruptly

=INFO REPORT==== 5-May-2016::11:37:25 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.955.14> (10.50.0.3:59774 -> 10.50.0.123:5672)

=WARNING REPORT==== 5-May-2016::11:37:27 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.955.14> (10.50.0.3:59774 -> 10.50.0.123:5672):
connection_closed_abruptly

=ERROR REPORT==== 5-May-2016::11:37:27 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.941.14> (10.50.0.3:59665 -> 10.50.0.123:5672):
{handshake_timeout,handshake}

=INFO REPORT==== 5-May-2016::11:37:29 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.962.14> (10.50.0.3:59796 -> 10.50.0.123:5672)

=WARNING REPORT==== 5-May-2016::11:37:30 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.670.14> (10.50.0.3:58769 -> 10.50.0.123:5672):
connection_closed_abruptly

=INFO REPORT==== 5-May-2016::11:37:35 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.972.14> (10.50.0.3:59814 -> 10.50.0.123:5672)

=INFO REPORT==== 5-May-2016::11:37:36 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.975.14> (10.50.0.3:59824 -> 10.50.0.123:5672)

=WARNING REPORT==== 5-May-2016::11:37:36 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.975.14> (10.50.0.3:59824 -> 10.50.0.123:5672):
connection_closed_abruptly

=ERROR REPORT==== 5-May-2016::11:37:39 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.962.14> (10.50.0.3:59796 -> 10.50.0.123:5672):
{handshake_timeout,handshake}

=INFO REPORT==== 5-May-2016::11:37:44 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.993.14> (10.50.0.3:59872 -> 10.50.0.123:5672)

=WARNING REPORT==== 5-May-2016::11:37:45 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.705.14> (10.50.0.3:58934 -> 10.50.0.123:5672):
connection_closed_abruptly

=ERROR REPORT==== 5-May-2016::11:37:45 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.972.14> (10.50.0.3:59814 -> 10.50.0.123:5672):
{handshake_timeout,handshake}

=INFO REPORT==== 5-May-2016::11:37:46 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.1005.14> (10.50.0.3:59881 -> 10.50.0.123:5672)

=WARNING REPORT==== 5-May-2016::11:37:46 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.1005.14> (10.50.0.3:59881 -> 10.50.0.123:5672):
connection_closed_abruptly

=INFO REPORT==== 5-May-2016::11:37:47 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.1010.14> (10.50.0.3:59892 -> 10.50.0.123:5672)
```

Going back a few minutes we see blocks of this several times:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 5-May-2016::11:28:25 ===
Mirrored queue 'bus-JEMSO04-w3wp-ktbyyynsicyfb1scbdjzj6targ' in vhost 'Beta': Adding mirror on node rabbit@redisd01: <18045.5072.16>

=INFO REPORT==== 5-May-2016::11:28:25 ===
Mirrored queue 'bus-JEMSO04-w3wp-ktbyyynsicyfb1scbdjzj6targ' in vhost 'Beta': Adding mirror on node rabbit@redisd02: <6520.2073.16>

=INFO REPORT==== 5-May-2016::11:28:25 ===
Mirrored queue 'bus-JEMSO04-w3wp-ktbyyynsicyfb1scbdjzj6targ' in vhost 'Beta': Synchronising: 0 messages to synchronise

=INFO REPORT==== 5-May-2016::11:28:25 ===
Mirrored queue 'bus-JEMSO04-w3wp-ktbyyynsicyfb1scbdjzj6targ' in vhost 'Beta': Synchronising: all slaves already synced

=INFO REPORT==== 5-May-2016::11:28:25 ===
Mirrored queue 'bus-JEMSO04-w3wp-ktbyyynsicyfb1scbdjzj6targ' in vhost 'Beta': Synchronising: 0 messages to synchronise

=INFO REPORT==== 5-May-2016::11:28:25 ===
Mirrored queue 'bus-JEMSO04-w3wp-ktbyyynsicyfb1scbdjzj6targ' in vhost 'Beta': Synchronising: all slaves already synced

=ERROR REPORT==== 5-May-2016::11:28:26 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.32168.13> (10.50.0.3:47716 -> 10.50.0.123:5672):
{handshake_timeout,handshake}
```

### Edit 2 - Updated to MassTransit 3.3.3

We have a new issue after upgrading, this is coming from our consumer and is not under load:

```
MassTransit.Util.TaskSupervisor Error: 0 : Failed to close scope MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Pipeline.RabbitMqBasicConsumer - rabbitmq://rabbitmqdlb.jsa.local:5672/LocalDev/bus-MRHODEN-DT-Se
rvice.vshost-xabyyydu3ecy84dibdjamdsbrb?prefetch=16, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Pipeline.RabbitMqBasicConsumer.<Stop>d__32.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at MassTransit.Util.TaskSupervisorExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<<CreateParticipant>b__0>d.MoveNext()
```

Comment: If you crank up logging on the RabbitMQ server itself, do you see a message correlated with this happening? A more complete call stack would help figure out where this is occurring, I'm not sure where to start with more details.

Comment: I added clips from that time-frame. They're pretty large files, do you need to see the full thing? I can probably upload it to drive and provide a link since I can't upload to SO.

Comment: Whoa this looks like your cluster is failing. And having to heal. You're seeing partitions.

Comment: Is there anything at the MassTransit API level that I can use to prevent the consuming service from tanking?

Comment: Well, this seems like an error due to a strange way of a connection being terminated. I'll have to try to reproduce it, since there is a very limited .NET call stack shown.

Comment: If it helps, we had a huge buildup of messages from running a lot of intense load tests. You could try just sending a queue a ton of messages and don't bother attempting consuming until you're using up a lot of memory.

Comment: Okay, so v3.3.3 was released, which resolves issues with the endpoint cache that may have caused some weird things to happen that others reported in a similar way. Not a guarantee, but just something to try.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your hard work, Chris! We integrated the latest and will report back if we see the issue again.

Comment: Any update? I've got same issue.

Comment: Sorry @Pawel you'll have to fix it, nothing I can do at this point.